# Position: Sticky not consistent between Mac and Windows devices on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-position, sticky

Just a note when running the code, the spacing will get thrown off if it is not run in full screen mode.

I'm having an issue with using position: sticky on some table elements. The issue is [this gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYGA2.png), seen between the top three table rows. This gap seems to only be present on Google Chrome on Mac devices. On a windows device on Google Chrome there [is no gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3qcl.png).

We have also tested other browsers and the table displays properly across all of them. It's just Mac Chrome that seems to have this issue.

For reference, here is the code making the three rows of this table sticky. The rest of the CSS is pretty standard table styling.

```css
.follow1{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index:2;
}
.follow2{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top:8.5%;
  background:#f9f9f9 !important;
}
.follow3{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top:14.5%;
  background:#f9f9f9 !important;
  color:black !important;
  border-bottom:1px dotted lightgray;
}

/*==========Decorative css==========*/
.offer-table table{
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 15px 0px;
}
.offer-table table td{
  font-size:16px;
  padding:1rem;
  border-top:1px dotted lightgray;
}
.offer-table .table-orange td{
  color:#ff612c;
  border-top:none;
  font-size:20px;
}
.offer-table table td:first-child{
  text-align:right;
}
.offer-table table td:not(:first-child){
  border-left:1px solid lightgray;
  border-right:1px solid lightgray;
  background:#f9f9f9;
  text-align:center;
  width:25%;
}
.offer-table table thead td{
  border:none;
  color:white;
}
.offer-table table thead td:not(:first-child){
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:18px;
  line-height:1.2rem;
  padding:1.5rem;
}
.offer-table table thead td:nth-child(2){
  background:#554971;
  border:1px solid lightgray;/*These need to change*/
  border-bottom:none;
}
.offer-table table thead td:nth-child(3){
  background:#63768d;
  border:1px solid lightgray;/*These need to change*/
  border-bottom:none;
}
.offer-table table thead td:nth-child(4){
  background:#8ac6d0;
  border:1px solid lightgray;/*These need to change*/
  border-bottom:none;
}
.offer-table .table-colors td:nth-child(2),.offer-table .table-colors td:nth-child(3){
  color:#0095ff;
}
.red{
  color:#ff612c !important;
}
.offer-table .table-colors td:nth-child(4){
  color:#ff612c;
}

.offer-table .black td:nth-child(4),.offer-table .custom-color-1 td:nth-child(3),.offer-table .custom-color-2 td:nth-child(2){
  color:black;
}
.offer-table .custom-color-2 td:nth-child(3){
  color:#ff612c;
}
.color-blue td:nth-child(4){
  color:#0095ff !important;
}
.cta-table div{
  width:100%;
}
.cta-table{
  border-bottom:1px solid lightgray;
}
.white{
  background:white !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-table">
<table>
<thead>
<tr class="table-headings">
<td class="follow1 white">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="follow1">Successful Business<br>Edition</td>
<td class="follow1">Successful Practice<br>Edition</td>
<td class="follow1">Start Up Practice<br>Edition</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-orange">
<td class="follow2 white">Upfront License</td>
<td class="follow2">$13,996</td>
<td class="follow2">$9,995</td>
<td class="follow2">$7,995</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="follow3 white">Ongoing Monthly License</td>
<td class="follow3">$139.95</td>
<td class="follow3">$119.95</td>
<td class="follow3">$59.95</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td><a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>Staff Access</strong></a></td>
<td>5 Staff Users<br><em>Additional Staff $10 user/month</em></td>
<td class="red">✖</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>Business Procedure Manuals</strong></a></td>
<td>All<br>Manuals</td>
<td>All<br>Manuals</td>
<td>Choice of<br>One Manual</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Quickbooks Desktop</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Quickbooks Online</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>Online Certification Programs</strong></a></td>
<td>All<br>Certification Programs</td>
<td>All<br>Certification Programs</td>
<td>Choice of<br>One Certification Program</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Quickbooks Desktop</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Quickbooks Online</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>Standard Operating Procedure Checklists</strong></a></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Client Automation Implementation Checklists</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Session Checklist</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Filing Checklist</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Year End Checklist</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Payroll Checklist</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Quarterly Reporting Checklist</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Quarterly Finance Fitness Review Checklists</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>Sales &amp; Marketing Module</strong></a></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Business Identity Template</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Website Templates</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Sales Conversion Scripts</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Sales Presentation Scripts</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Referral System</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Networking System</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Marketing Templates</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Sales Conversion Scripts</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>Human Resources Module</strong></a></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Advertising Templates &amp; Guidelines</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Applicant Filter</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Phone Qualification Process</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Candidate Skills &amp; Speed Test</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Interview Questions &amp; Evaluation</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>New Hire Onboarding Program</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>New Hire Training Program</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>Standard Operating Procedures Cloud Apps</strong></a></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Workflow/Practice Management Software</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Document Retrieval</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Document Storage</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>CRM</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Time Tracking</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Payment Apps</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Virtual Communication</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Payroll Apps</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Value Added Service Apps</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>E-Signatures</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Security</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Accounting Software Dashboards</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>Business Success Support</strong></a></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Unlimited Support</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Unlimited Updates</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Monthly Success Calls</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Weekly Group Mentoring Calls</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Exclusive Licensee Only Facebook Group</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Knowledge Base Forums</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors color-blue">
<td>Guided Implementation and Getting Started Program</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors">
<td>Access to Monthly Group Mastermind</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>check</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-colors custom-color-2">
<td><a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>Accelerate 2 Advisor</strong></a><br><em>Mentoring Program</em></td>
<td><em>Can be Added<br>$10,000 Anually</em></td>
<td>✖</td>
<td>✖</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="cta-table"></td>
<td class="cta-table"></td>
<td class="cta-table"></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

The top three table rows contain the appropriate classes to make them all scroll with each other. The intended effect is to have the top three rows of the table scroll with the user through the rest of the table.

Comment: May be related to the top value being in percentages, does it work properly if you use fixed values? no way to tell for sure without seeing a minimal example

Comment: "We have also tested other browsers and the table displays properly across all of them" so it looks fine on Safari and Firefox for Mac? Just curious if it's a Retina-related issue or something else like the available viewport size depending on the browser's chrome (URL bar, bookmarks, etc).